# How to obtain the ID Value of a select populated with axios and Vue

Tags: post, drop-down-menu, vue.js, axios

I have a

```
<select id="ddlTipoUsuario" class="form-control" >
   <option v-for="tipoUsuario in tipoUsuarios">{{tipoUsuario.Tipo}}</option>
</select>
```

populated with Vue and axios, but I need to obtain the ID Value to post in another table. 
In the response.data returns these values:

```
[ { 
    "TipoUsuarioId": 1, 
    "Tipo": "Administrador" 
  }, 
  { 
    "TipoUsuarioId": 2, 
    "Tipo": "Usuario" 
  } ]
```

To populate my `<select>` i use this code:

```
export default {
    data() {
       return {
           tipoUsuarios:[],
         }
    },
method: {
   getTipoUsuario() {
     axios.get("http://localhost:50995/api/GetTipoUsuario")
     .then(response => {
           this.tipoUsuarios = response.data,
           this.status = response.data
      })
      .catch(e => {
           console.log(e)
      })
   }
}
```

This is my POST method for now:

```
 addUsuario() {
            axios.post("http://localhost:50995/api/PostUsuario", {
                "Nombre": this.nombre,
                "ApellidoP": this.apellidoP,
                "ApellidoM": this.apellidoM,
                "Email": this.email,
                "NombreUsuario": this.nombreUsuario,
                "Contrasena": this.password
            })

        },
```

I need to generate a POST with the value of the ID when i select one option of the `<select>`.

Thank You.

Comment: Where should the ID go? I mean, you say you need it, but don't say where you exactly would use it.

Comment: I need the ID in my POST method, to save it in a data base

Comment: Where, exactly? Show how would you do it if you had it.

Comment: To the database, it is a relationship between tables. I'm just practicing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a `v-model` on the `<select>` to a data property to store the selected value, and add the `:value` to the `<option>`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    types: [{id: 1, name: 'admin'}, {id: 2, name: 'user'}],
    selectedType: 1
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="example">
  <select v-model="selectedType">
      <option 
          v-for="item in types" :value="item.id">
         {{ item.name }}
      </option>
  </select>
  Selected: {{ selectedType }}
</div>
```

Take a look at the example in [Form Input Bindigs: Select](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select) from official documentation

Answer (score 0):

When you select one of the options, the `select` will fire a `change` event, which you can catch and send to a method:

```
<select id="ddlTipoUsuario" class="form-control" @change="selectChange" >
   <option v-for="tipoUsuario in tipoUsuarios">{{tipoUsuario.Tipo}}</option>
</select>
```

The method will receive a normal Event object as its argument. You can get the `id` from it in the usual way:

```
selectChange(event) {
  this.selectId = event.target.id;
  this.selectedOption = event.target.value; // you probably also want this
}
```