# How can I give specific parameter to a v-model call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, v-model

How can I give the index of my array days, in the v-model ?

```
<select v-model="dayList" id="dayList">
    <option v-for="(day, index) in days" :key="index">{{ selectDaysLabel(day) }}</option>
</select>
```

And:

```
dayList(index) {
  console.log(index) // should give you either 0, 1, 2...
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can you show `days`? It's a bit hard to understand as it is. Do you have a `data` property called `dataList`? Or is it just a method?

Comment: You are missing the :value property on the option tag. Maybe this will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49396221/how-to-obtain-the-id-value-of-a-select-populated-with-axios-and-vue/49396435#49396435

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the value of `<option>` with specific data type as you need like `v-bind:value="{ 'data': day, 'index':index }"`, or simply you can `v-bind:value="index"`.

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        selectedDay: '',
        days: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    },
    methods: {
      getSelect(){
        console.log(this.selectedDay ? this.selectedDay.index : 'No selection')
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.1/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<button v-on:click="getSelect()">Test</button>
<select v-model="selectedDay" >
    <option v-for="(day, index) in days" v-bind:value="{ 'data': day, 'index':index }">{{day}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```